# Using NSFetchedResultsController(s) from two entities

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm showing user's status messages and comments on those messages in UITableView and trying to save data using Core Data.
I just learned how to use NSFetchedResultsController in UITableView, however most cases of using NSFetchedResultsController is for just one entity.
I'd like to store user's status messages in one entity and comments in another entity, and divide UITableView into sections: one section for each status message. The first row (UITableViewCell) of every section is status message and other rows of the same section are comments on that message: showing like the followings

```
status message 1
 comment
 comment
 ...
 comment
status message 2
 comment
 comment
 ...
 comment
...
```

I think I have to use TWO NSFetchedResultsControllers - one for status messages, one for comments - but can't figure out how to set NSFetchedResultsController for comments.
Any good idea?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` has already sections and sections headers. Your task will get a lot easier if you display the status messages in the section header for each section, and only the comments in the table view rows.

You would need only one fetched results controller for "Comment", but you have to set the `sectionNameKeyPath:` of the FRC and provide a sort descriptor to group the results of the FRC into sections according to the status messages.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but problem is that section headers are floating during vertical scrolling and I don't want it since sometimes status message is enough long for table view cell to fill entire screen. :(

Comment: @josh: OK. You could add a dummy comment object to each status object which is ordered first within all comments for that status. Then you need only one FRC for comment, and the dummy comment cells display the status message.

Comment: thanks your idea. I'm thinking of saving both status messages in comments as the same entity, which needs to be more general. If it doesn't go well, I'll try your suggestion. Thanks!